# Bash $RANDOM exceeding bounds

Tags: bash, random

I'm having a little bit of trouble with a bash script that is intended to produce a random number between 100 and 999.

My script is as follows:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
    pin=$((( $RANDOM % 999) +100))
    echo $pin
done
```

Below is a sample of the output.  As you can see, some of the numbers exceed 999.  What might be going on here?

```
626
901
1094
456
290
1047
265
221
483
626
848
198
879
474
993
205
200
229
391
325
306
201
800
1004
694
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Grabbed the code snippet from another Stack Overflow post which detailed the method for 1-10 and saw the same posted elsewhere online.  Their instructions were (so to speak) 10% off.  And when I read it, I hadn't it interpreted the syntax as a derivative of bash's arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ($RANDOM % 999) is in range 0 to 999, your output is (($RANDOM % 999) + 100), which is in range 100 to 1099. Is (($RANDOM + 100) % 999) instead of (($RANDOM % 999) + 100) what you want?

Comment: Rather, the thing they say they want would be `(RANDOM % 900) + 100`, since they want the range to start at 100 rather than 0. Doing the addition first doesn't actually take 0-100 out of the range of possibilities -- think about what happens if `RANDOM + 100` is 1000; `1000 % 999` is 1, so they get 1, not 100, with your proposal here.

Comment: ...or, to explain it a different way: If `RANDOM` rolls 905, and you add 100 before the `%` operator applies, then you're running `1005 % 999`, and you get 6, which is less than 100 and thus should by intent be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

To emit 1000 numbers between 100 and 999:

```
for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do
  echo "$(( ( RANDOM % 900 ) + 100 ))"
done
```

Keep in mind that `900 % 900` is 0, meaning that the maximum value possible as output is 899, so if you want your values (after addition) to be through 999 inclusive, you use 900, not 899.